# How does C++ char* comparison work?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    if ("zabc" < "def") {
        std::cout << "Less.\n";
    }
}
```

The code above prints `Less.`. I know this is not the right way to compare `char*`s in C++, but how does the above code print `Less.`?

Comment: Isn't this one of those RTFM questions?

Comment: He said "I know this is not the right way to compare char*s in C++". I think it's reasonable to ask why the "wrong way" behaves as it does.

Comment: The code has undefined behaviour: You can only less-than-compare pointers to subobjects of the same object.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Unspecified, not undefined. Calling `reformat_hard_drive()` is an acceptable response to comparing a `char*` to an `int*` because that comparison is undefined behavior. It is not an acceptable response to comparing a random `char*` to another random `char*`. This is just unspecified behavior. You might now know what you'll get, but the result must be a `bool` rather than an empty hard drive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code compares the addresses of the two strings. Formally, that's unspecified behavior, since they are not elements of the same array, but in this case it's probably telling the truth: the first string has a lower address than the second. But you can't count on that...

Comment: Incidentally, `std::less<T*>` does define a total order, so `std::less<char**>("zabc", "abc")` has a well-defined result (this probably needs a `const` or two...). For what it's worth...

Comment: It's unspecified behaviour, rather than undefined. See §5.9/2: "If two pointers p and q of the same type point to different objects that are not members of the same object or elements of the same array or to different functions, or if only one of them is null, the results of p<q, p>q, p<=q, and p>=q are unspecified."

Answer (score 7):

You are just comparing the addresses. You need to use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/)

Comment: Isn't this for `const char*` only?

Answer (score 2):

It's comparing addresses. "zabc" happens to be at a lower address than "def" for some particular invocation of this code compiled by some particular compiler. (It could also be at a higher address depending on the compiler and possibly even for different invocations of the same executable.)

Answer (score 2):

When you do that, the compiler allocates two char arrays, one for "def" and one for "zabc".
This is done at compilation time.

Since "zabc" is defined before "def", your compiler probably gives the first one the smaller address, although this is an undefined behaviour. later when the addresses are compared, "zabc" is "smaller". You should see that if you do the next, you will still get "Less" printed.

```
 if ("def" < "zabc") {
    std::cout << "Less.\n";
}
```