# Compare pointer chars

Tags: c++, pointers, char

First of all I have searched a lot and also tried many things but unfortunately no solution for my problem.

Below, I tried to compare two char* values. But I do not understand why this does not work. What my intention is that this function performs the sendCommand() only when temp does not equal IDMilight. 
Temp values will be different if there is an adjustment to the database.
So if there issn't any adjustment it must delay for 2sec and check again.

I'm pretty new to C++ so I hope someone can help me with this

```
static char *IDMilight = new char;
static char *temp = new char;

void mysql_query_connection(){        
    if (!mysql_query(mysql1, "SELECT IDMilight, Hex FROM Milight ORDER BY IDMilight DESC LIMIT 1"))
    {
        MYSQL_RES* result = mysql_store_result(mysql1);
        MYSQL_ROW row = mysql_fetch_row(result);
        temp = row[0];

        if (*temp != *IDMilight) {
            IDMilight = row[0];
            hexCode = row[1];
            sentCommand();
        }
    }
}
```

The following if statments i also tried, but unfortunately that does not work either:

```
if (temp != IDMilight)
if (&temp != &IDMilight)
```

And if I print the value's they are not equal to each other.

Comment: You seem to have quite a few misunderstandings about C++. You should take a step back and systematically learn the language from a  good book.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Yes, particularly pointers. BTW the code could be also compiled as C.

Comment: @BaummitAugen, thanks for you reaction. Can u please tell me the misunderstandings?

Comment: @Matthijs If I could do that in 600 characters, there would be no need for C++ books. :)

Comment: @Melebius thanks for your reaction. This is only a small part of my code. so it cannot be compiled as C.

Comment: @BaummitAugen So this 11 lines of code you need 600 chars to explain what there is wrong? And again, this is only a small part of my functionality.

Comment: The problem is that you are missing core concepts of C++. I *could* throw a snippet that probably does what you want into the answer box, and you could copy-paste that, but that's just not a way to learn C++. You would continue to write bad code, run into trouble, most like produce wrong code that looks like it works without noticing and so on. So that's a bad idea and thus I advice you to read a C++ book instead.

Comment: The &temp != &IDMilight line shows pretty much that you use code without knowing what it does. Don't. This will result in terrible bugs. If you see a line of code that you don't understand, the logical thing is to change that, to learn what it does. Through tutorials or by simply asking someone. Totally fine to copy some code from the web, but not without learning how it does things. &temp is the address of temp, by the way. In this case, read a good tutorial on pointers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does C++ char\* comparison work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677837/how-does-c-char-comparison-work)

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are pretty new to C++, the right answer is this:

Don't use `char*`. Try to avoid pointers at all and if you have to use them, use pointer classes like `unique_ptr`. One simple reason, for example, is that you have to manage memory if those pointers don't simply point at some other variables that exist within some scope. Thus, memory leaks are quite easy to produce if you use pointers. (That said, you can use pointers, but usually you do this in some controlled environment, like wrapped within some class, like a linked list class, or in a very small scope in which you need polymorphy - although again, in such a case you could use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`)

Pointers that are essentially arrays like the typically used `char*` should be replaced by something that wraps arrays. In this case, clearly `std::string`, which can be used just like `char*`. In other cases, for example instead of `int*` or `int[]` arrays, you'd use `std::vector`.

Now, you have some function from outside that you need for SQL, that's ok, but try to limit the time in which something stays a `char*`. Transform `char*` to string simply by putting it in the constructor: `std::string my_string(functions_that_returns_char());`, then compare simply by `string_1 == string_2`. You can access single letters as usual by `my_string[some_index]`. Take a look yourself for more functionality:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/

That said, I can only second the comment from Baum mit Augen, get a book or read through some tutorials. `And be aware that C-style is totally not C++-style, C-programmers will use pointers a lot, for instance.`

As for your original question, a pointer that is essentially an array points to the first element of that array. Dereferencing produces that element, not the array. No need to use a pointer here anyway if you could simply directly use the actual array, right?

Comment: What you explain make sense thanks you for that. And you are correct, i will try it without the pointers.

Comment: Thanks, again! It's working now;) Just converted the char* to a string.